# Change component of JPanel that has been changed by an ActionListener from another ActionListener

Tags: java

I have some buttons in my `JPlane` and when I click them, I want each one of them to change the components of the `JPanel` without interference, as in, when I click one button, two `JTextFields` are added to the `JPlane`; however, when I press the other button, I want the previous `JTextField`s to get removed and instead add one new `JTextField`. My code looks something like this:

```java
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField name1 = new JTextField();
        JLabel salary = new JLabel("Salary");
        JTextField salary1 = new JTextField();

        low.add(name);
        low.add(name1);
        low.add(salary);
        low.add(salary1);
    }
});

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField name1 = new JTextField();

        low.add(name);
        low.add(name1);
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be a good use for a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).